# How to split a string using regex with beginning character matches any of this <= | >= | = | !=

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a situation where I have to split a string by checking a condition whether a string begins with any of this character "<= | >= | = | !="

- `=>value` desired result `[=>,value]`
- `>=value` desired result `[>=,value]`
- `somevalue` desired result `[somevalue]`

My attempt

```
var string1 = '<=value';
var splitString = string1.split(/\s+(?:<=|>=|=|!=)\s+/);
console.log(splitString);
```

Comment: you've got nothing to split on! have you tried anything yourself at all? or are you after a code monkey?

Comment: hey sorry i am new two regex

Comment: Your single `=` is going to conflict with `=>` when attempting to match the start sequence

Comment: `'<=value'.split(/<=|>=|=|!=/)` returns `["", "value"]`.

Comment: by the way ... `=>` ... and `>=` ... but your attempt has `<=` and `>=` ... confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the outputs you require

note: the `.map` at the end is to remove the blank entry in the case of `somevalue`

```
input.match(/(<=|>=|=|!=)?\s*(.+)/).slice(1)).map(x => x.slice(x[0] === undefined ? 1 : 0)
```

The snippet below tests all three of your inputs, (plus the other two you never mentioned in the examples) - which is why it's wrapped in `inputs.map(input => ....)`

```js
const inputs = ['<=value', '>=value', '!= value', '=value', 'somevalue'];
const outputs = inputs.map(input => input.match(/(>=|<=|=|\!=)?\s*(.+)/).slice(1)).map(x => x.slice(x[0] === undefined ? 1 : 0));
console.log(outputs);
```

note: your question asks for `<=`, `>=`, `!=` or `=`
and your attempted regex is  `<=`, `>=`, `!=` or `=`
and then your examples have  `=>`, `>=`  only?

your regex doesn't even look for `=>`!

So, I've amended the example "inputs" to be sane ... i.e. using what the question and attempted regex ask for - I think your input examples were hastily put together :p

Answer (score 0):

There can possibly be multiple correct answers, but I think the shortest is this

`[<>!](?:=)|=`

You can test or try modifications here: https://regex101.com/r/kXIOvx/1 . This is a good site for regex newbies or even veterans when they don't want to run the whole program just to verify a regex line (which you have to do everytime you write a regex line)

Comment: how does this produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Groups `()` are included in the `split` result, and `filter` can be used to remove empty entries:

```js
var re = /([<>!]?=)/g

console.log( '<=value'.split(re).filter(Boolean) )
console.log( '=value'.split(re).filter(Boolean) )
console.log( 'value'.split(re) )
```

Or `match` instead of splitting:

```js
var re = /[<>!]?=|.+/g

console.log( '<=value'.match(re) )
console.log( '=value'.match(re) )
console.log( 'value'.match(re) )
```

Comment: @JaromandaX `=>` in the example is by mistake if you notice the `>=` in the title, question, and attempt

Comment: sorry, the question is all over the shop ... I think it should be <=, >=, != or = as you have :p